# How to get a variable attribute of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat in which I have set an attribute like so:

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList"
     stepType="{{item.stepType}}">
     {{item.itemValue}}
</div>
```

item.stepType can have values 'task' or 'action'
I'm trying to get the attribute 'stepType' like so:

```
let stepType = el.getAttributeNode("stepType");
console.log(stepType.value);
```

The result  i'm getting is:

```
{{item.stepType}}
```

But the expected result is `task` or `action`

I also tried to get the attribute using the function `getAttribute()` but the result is the same.

I also noticed that in the above code if i log the value of `stepType` instead of `stepType.value`, i get the object which looks like this `stepType: 'task'`

How can i get the expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute name is [normalized](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization):

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList"
     step-type="{{item.stepType}}">
     {{item.itemValue}}
</div>
```

A custom AngularJS directive can [`$observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) the attribute:

```js
app.directive("stepType", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe("stepType", function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
})
```

The console will log changes to the interpolated value of the attribute.

Comment: This actually works - attrs gets me the value of any attribute which otherwise was not getting evaluated

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the double quotes. Replace this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList"
     stepType="{{item.stepType}}">
     {{item.itemValue}}
</div>
```

with

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList"
     stepType={{item.stepType}}>
     {{item.itemValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the same result, no change